# Proof of compactness of a set by Borel-Lebesgue definition

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Given the following set

Let $ x \in B[(0,0),1]$ in $\mathbb{R^2} $

How do I proof that the set $A = B[(0,0),1] - \{x\}$ is not compact by using Lebesgue-Borel theorem/condition/definition?

Comment: Will you provide the definition? There are very many ways to prove this is not compact

Comment: Heine-Borel is the more common name. And $A$ is not closed as $x$ lies in its closure.

Comment: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Borel-Lebesgue_covering_theorem

Comment: What does $B[(0,0),1]$ denote (why brackets)? Let $A_n=\{y:d(x,y)>1/n\}$ and consider the open cover by these sets, $n=1,2,3,...$

Comment: @Mirko I think it stands for the closed ball of that centre and radius.

Comment: Yes, it denotes what @HennoBrandsma said.